# The meaning of 东瞧西瞅?

Tags: meaning, idioms

In Mandarin translation of Little Red Riding Hood that can be found around ([Grimm Stories](https://www.grimmstories.com/zh/grimm_tonghua/xiaohongmao), [BaiDuBaiKe](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%B0%8F%E7%BA%A2%E5%B8%BD/5286)), mother warns Little Red Riding Hood: "外婆家的时候，别忘了说‘早上好’，也不要一进屋就东瞧西瞅。" How would you translate 东瞧西瞅 in this sentence? I have seen translations like "look around" but it does not seem to make much sense in the context.

Answer (score 2):

The original English text for the excerpt you’ve given above is:

> And when you go into her room, don't forget to say, good-morning, and don't peep into every corner before you do it."

So here “peep into every corner” was translated 东瞧西䐐. It’s a fairly true translation.

Comment: Thank you @user3306356, you are right. Even though [Grimm Stories](https://www.grimmstories.com/en/grimm_fairy-tales/little_red_cap) does not have that version, other sources (e.g. [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Grimm%27s_Household_Tales,_vol.1.djvu/192)) do. In this, a bit archaic, context "peep into every corner" has a negative connotation, as in being rude. Does 东瞧西䐐 have that feel to?

Comment: @celaeno Absolutely. A more common phrase would be 东张西望 or you could even just say something like 东看西看, but it's always negative in connotation.

Answer (score 1):

this structure 东V西V could means:

1 do sth repeatedly and **blindly**

2 do sth repeatedly and **leisurely**

3 do sth repeatedly and **curiously**

4 do sth repeatedly

In your sentence, it means "keeps looking around curiously".

Similarly:

东跑西颠, 东倚西靠 keeps XX leisurely

东躲西藏, 东拉西扯: keeps xx blindly

东奔西跑 just means "run around here and there", doesn't imply more information.

Answer (score 0):

东瞧西瞅 literally means **look the east and the west**.  If we extend its literal meaning, it would be  **look here and there** or **look around**.